# Beginning jasperReport/iReport with Grails

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, ireport, jasper-plugin

I want to create a report for my domain class instances but not all, just the ones user selected in the GSP table (selecting checkboxes). On my report  I will also have some logic - few conditionals, some calculations etc. I would also have to get some additional data from database. How do I do this? Should I get values of selected checkboxes in cotroller and pass it to jasper cotroller? Something like this:

GSP:

```
 <g:each in="${books}" var="bookInstance">
        <td> <g:checkBox name="book_${bookInstance.id}"/> </td>
 </g:each>
```

Action:

```
def bookReport = {
    def bookList = []
    params.each {
        if(it.key.startsWith("book_")){
            bookList.add((it.key - "book_") as Long)
        }
    }

    def bookCriteria = Book.createCriteria()
    def books = bookCriteria.list {
        'in'('id',bookList)
    }
    chain(controller:'jasper', data:books, action:'index', params:params)
}
```

I used iReport for report creation. I've tried creating report without SQL query and parameters. My logic was that if I pass a map of domain instances to jasper controller as I did in the example above I dont need to specify data source in report. But I get an empty report.

I also tried seting the report datasource to my database and report query to this: select * from book where $X{IN,id,books}. In that case, no matter what I select report is created for all book instances.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
chain(controller:'jasper', model:[data:books], action:'index', params:params)
```

...while leaving the SQL string empty in your .jrxml?